# Loop partitions disappear on rebind

Tags: linux, block-device, loop-device

When I create a 400MB file called /tmp/foo, then call `losetup -f /tmp/foo`, this creates a loop device `/dev/loop15`. If I then partition the loopdevice and format it to contain ext4,ntfs, and fat32 filesystems respectively, then run lsblk, I get the following:

```
loop15        7:15   0 390,6M  0 loop 
├─loop15p1  259:8    0   100M  0 part 
├─loop15p2  259:9    0   200M  0 part 
└─loop15p3  259:10   0    83M  0 part
```

under /etc/dev there is then loop15, loop15p1, loop15p2, and loop15p3.

but after calling `losetup -d /dev/loop15` to unbind the loop device, then recall `losetup -f /tmp/foo` to rebind it, then when running gparted or KDE disk manager, both show me that there are 3 partitions on the device, but all of them unformatted. If I run `lsblk -f` or `ls /dev/loop*` I see `/dev/loop15`, but the partitions are gone.

Is there a way to make the filesystems persistent across un-/binds? How do I restore the blockdevice nodes to the partitions (loop15p1,loop15p2,loop15p3...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `losetup` with `-P`/`--partscan` to tell kernel to scan for partitions on the device, it's not enabled by default for loop devices so the partition device nodes are not created without this option.